# Execute the same SQL update statement for a number of tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have 6 different tables in sql server that I want to run the following script against. is it possible to do it in some sort of a loop?

```
UPDATE Table
    SET fk =CASE fk
    WHEN 1 THEN 15
    WHEN 2 THEN 16
    WHEN 3 THEN 17
    WHEN 4 THEN 11
    WHEN 5 THEN 12
    WHEN 6 THEN 13
    WHEN 7 THEN 14
    END
    WHERE fk IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
    UPDATE Table SET fk = fk - 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below... It will help you...

Pass your table name by comma separated...

```
DECLARE @test varchar(max);
Declare @Count int;
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
set @test = '#temp,#temp1,#temp2,#temp3'; --Table Names Separate by Commas
set @test = Replace(@test, ',', '.')
select @Count = len(@test) - len(replace(@test, '.', ''))
WHILE (@intFlag <= @Count + 1)
BEGIN
Declare @tablename as varchar(100)
Declare @sqlquery as varchar(5000)
Select @tablename = ParseName(@test, @intFlag )
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'UPDATE ' + @tablename  
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'SET fk = (CASE fk '    
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 1 THEN 15    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 2 THEN 16    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 3 THEN 17    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 4 THEN 11    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 5 THEN 12    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 6 THEN 13    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'WHEN 7 THEN 14    '
SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'END)  WHERE fk IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)     UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET fk = fk - 10'
print @sqlquery
exec(@sqlquery)
SEt @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible unless you write a cursor in which you have to get the table names either manually or by selecting the tabel names up to a condition from the system tables from `sys.Tables`

---

You will need to use dynamic sql as Nikola Markovinović mentioned in his comment so you can provide the table name as a parameter which you handle as a table name then.

like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updTable @Tablename nvarchar(30)
AS
UPDATE @Tablename ... 
Your script here ...
GO
```

Call it for each table like:

```
EXEC updTable 'yourTableName'
```

Or create a cursor which does this for you like:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(30) 
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM SYS.Tables 
WHERE name IN ('YourTable_1','YourTable_2' ... , 'YourTable_N')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
  updTable @name    
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: I have the table names and I dont mind adding them in manually. can you provide an example of it being done using a cursor.

Comment: I didnt tested this code, i hope it works but you may need to modify it a bit.

Comment: You cannot substitute variable for table name: `select * from @table_name` is illegal (well, unless @table_name is table variable). You need to resort to [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović you are right, thank you. does the code syntax applies for dynamic sql or is it different?

Comment: Please check the article I've linked. In short, term dynamic sql refers to sql code stored in nvarchar variable and executed via [sp_execute_sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) or [exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx); former being better choice than latter.